# How much weight can a handle of Technic pegs and beams support?

Tags: technic, building, durability

Some Lego spaceships have handles attached, made out of Technic beam and pegs, and attached to the model using Technic bricks, pegs, and axles.

For example, [7644: MX-81 Hypersonic Operations Aircraft](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7644-1) has a handle on the top (circled below), and the shuttle in [7690: MB-01 Eagle Command Base](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7690-1) has a small handle on the bottom side.

[image: A cropped view of the MX-81 Hypersonic Operations Aircraft. The handled, positioned on the top center, is circled in red.]

This handle is great for play, transport, and mounting, and I'd like to incorporate this feature into my own designs. However, I don't know what a safe number of pegs and beams is relative to the weight of the model. To be really useful, it needs to support not just the weight of the model, but a reasonable amount of centrifugal force caused by rapid course adjustments as it flies around my living room. Are there official Lego Group guidelines on this, or has someone done a study of the strength of peg-and-beam constructions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Tristan Lostroh did an [exhaustive test](https://eprints.usq.edu.au/20528/1/Lostroh_LegoTesting_2012.pdf) of both studded beams and stud-less beams with and without connections. Here are his results:

> - Studless beams are better in tension than studded
> - Studded beams are better in transverse than studless
> - Studless beams are stronger in transverse with the pins on the side
> - Connections to other components will fail before the beam (Either connections themselves  or the connection area of the beam)(IE the
>     (unstressed) centre of the beam    will not fail)
> - Pin connections will probably pull apart before they fail catastrophically
> - The more pins, the stronger the connection
> - In transverse 3 pin overlap, with 2 pins used is almost as strong as 3 pin overlap and 3 pins used
> - Beams in transverse conditions won’t fail (but will bend) if the pivot points match the end of  the connection
> - Lego is quite strong for its weight

From the report it looks like two beams linked with 5 pins will break at about 57lb of transverse force.

**Edit**: Just for the fun of it I calculated this 'real life' scenario. Imagine a kid with 40cm  arms spinning around a 2lb Lego ship.  To create the 57lb of centrifugal force necessary to break the handle he would have to turn at 252rpm.  I don't think any amount of sugar can do that.

Comment: If only I could +2 for the edit - I'll ask my boys to try this evening after trick or treating ;)

Comment: After calculating it, I pictured my kid spinning like the Tasmanian Devil at 252rpm. I was laughing so hard I had a though time typing the edit.

Comment: A nice display of structural strenght is seen on the Millenium Falcon lego set 10179-1 : http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10179-1

Comment: The link now 404's

Comment: @AidanConnelly The link is now fixed